# Getting error when navigating SSRS report after login to portal using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie for selenium,
my company want to download data from SSRS report,
For this, i able to log to their portal but I am getting error when I am navigating default page to SSRS report

[image]

I am using below code, please guide me for this

```
IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https:xxxxxx");
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtLogin")).SendKeys("xyz");
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).SendKeys("xxx");

_driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit")).Click();  
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100); 
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?");
```

Comment: The `GoToUrl("...")` method sends a GET request to the server. You might be unable to navigate directly to that URL. Maybe try navigating first to `https://ReportServer` and then click links and buttons to nagivate to the appropriate report?

Comment: If you go to those URLs in a web browser (copy and paste them into the location bar, and then press ENTER), do you get the same server error?

Comment: Are you using the correct URL.  From start button in windows you can go to ssrs reports and click on the URL to verify it works.   Did you follow the instructions in the Error message?

Comment: Can you share the browser console error? Most of the time, navigating directly to the any internal page in companies are prohibited. can you login into the portal and try to navigate to the report ? Is this a possibility?